# Sonar Eclipse Plugin - get properties from Maven pom.xml for local analysis

Tags: maven, configuration, eclipse-plugin, sonarqube, checkstyle

I have problem with Sonar Eclipse Plugin and Sonar Local Analysis with combination of Checkstyle Suppression file configuration.

I'am using:

- Sonar 3.5.1
- Maven 3.0.4
- Eclipse Juno SR2
- latest version of Sonar Eclipse Plugin (3.1.1)

In SonarQube UI I set in Settings -> System -> General Settings -> Checkstyle -> Filters:

```
<module name="SuppressionCommentFilter" />
<module name="SuppressionFilter">
    <property name="file" value="${main.dir}/config/checkstyle-suppressions.xml" />
</module>
```

In my Maven pom.xml I have:

```
<properties>
    <sonar.exclusions>**/gener/*.java</sonar.exclusions>
    <main.dir>${basedir}/..</main.dir>
</properties>
```

When I run local analysis property *sonar.exclusions* is properly used, but for Checkstyle I get Exception:

```
org.xml.sax.SAXException: Property ${main.dir} has not been set
```

When I run "remote" analysis form Jenkins, *main.dir* is used properly.

So, why do not *main.dir* also used for local analysis? Or where is the problem?

In documentation is:

> Parameters to configure local analysis can be set in various places.
>   Here is the hierarchy of parameters:
>
> - Parameters defined in the SonarQube Web UI
> - Parameters set in the pom.xml file (for Maven projects only, with the m2e connector installed) will override parameters defined in the
>     UI
> - Parameters defined in Eclipse will override  parameters defined in the pom file (go to Window > Preferences > Sonar > Local analysis
>     properties)
> - Parameters defined at project level in Eclipse will override parameters defined at Eclipse level (right click on the project and go
>     to Properties > Sonar > Local analysis properties)

Thank you very much for any response.

Complete StackTrace:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.sonar.runner.impl.RunnerException: Unable to execute Sonar
    at org.sonar.runner.impl.BatchLauncher$1.delegateExecution(BatchLauncher.java:79)
    at org.sonar.runner.impl.BatchLauncher$1.run(BatchLauncher.java:63)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at org.sonar.runner.impl.BatchLauncher.doExecute(BatchLauncher.java:57)
    at org.sonar.runner.impl.BatchLauncher.execute(BatchLauncher.java:50)
    at org.sonar.runner.impl.BatchLauncherMain.execute(BatchLauncherMain.java:41)
    at org.sonar.runner.impl.BatchLauncherMain.main(BatchLauncherMain.java:59)
Caused by: org.sonar.api.utils.SonarException: Can not execute Checkstyle
    at org.sonar.plugins.checkstyle.CheckstyleExecutor.execute(CheckstyleExecutor.java:89)
    at org.sonar.plugins.checkstyle.CheckstyleSensor.analyse(CheckstyleSensor.java:44)
    at org.sonar.batch.phases.SensorsExecutor.execute(SensorsExecutor.java:70)
    at org.sonar.batch.phases.Phases.execute(Phases.java:101)
    at org.sonar.batch.scan.ScanContainer.doStart(ScanContainer.java:147)
    at org.sonar.batch.bootstrap.Container.start(Container.java:72)
    at org.sonar.batch.scan.ScanTask.scan(ScanTask.java:65)
    at org.sonar.batch.scan.ScanTask.scanRecursively(ScanTask.java:56)
    at org.sonar.batch.scan.ScanTask.execute(ScanTask.java:49)
    at org.sonar.batch.bootstrap.TaskContainer.doStart(TaskContainer.java:188)
    at org.sonar.batch.bootstrap.Container.start(Container.java:72)
    at org.sonar.batch.bootstrap.TaskBootstrapContainer.executeTask(TaskBootstrapContainer.java:73)
    at org.sonar.batch.bootstrap.TaskBootstrapContainer.doStart(TaskBootstrapContainer.java:62)
    at org.sonar.batch.bootstrap.Container.start(Container.java:72)
    at org.sonar.batch.bootstrap.BootstrapContainer.doStart(BootstrapContainer.java:104)
    at org.sonar.batch.bootstrap.Container.start(Container.java:72)
    at org.sonar.batch.bootstrapper.Batch.startBatch(Batch.java:88)
    at org.sonar.batch.bootstrapper.Batch.execute(Batch.java:72)
    at org.sonar.runner.batch.IsolatedLauncher.execute(IsolatedLauncher.java:45)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at org.sonar.runner.impl.BatchLauncher$1.delegateExecution(BatchLauncher.java:75)
    ... 6 more
Caused by: com.puppycrawl.tools.checkstyle.api.CheckstyleException: unable to read
C:\Development\Java\workspace\eclipse\Juno\SR2\x86\CSA\TRUNK\.metadata\.plugins
\org.eclipse.core.resources\.projects\mfgw-module-ffp-fbp-upgrade-core-ejb
\org.sonar.ide.eclipse.core\checkstyle.xml - unable to parse configuration stream - 
Property ${main.dir} has not been set
    at com.puppycrawl.tools.checkstyle.ConfigurationLoader.loadConfiguration(ConfigurationLoader.java:346)
    at com.puppycrawl.tools.checkstyle.ConfigurationLoader.loadConfiguration(ConfigurationLoader.java:286)
    at org.sonar.plugins.checkstyle.CheckstyleConfiguration.toCheckstyleConfiguration(CheckstyleConfiguration.java:113)
    at org.sonar.plugins.checkstyle.CheckstyleConfiguration.getCheckstyleConfiguration(CheckstyleConfiguration.java:107)
    at org.sonar.plugins.checkstyle.CheckstyleExecutor.execute(CheckstyleExecutor.java:83)
    ... 29 more
Caused by: com.puppycrawl.tools.checkstyle.api.CheckstyleException: unable to parse 
configuration stream - Property ${main.dir} has not been set
    at com.puppycrawl.tools.checkstyle.ConfigurationLoader.loadConfiguration(ConfigurationLoader.java:410)
    at com.puppycrawl.tools.checkstyle.ConfigurationLoader.loadConfiguration(ConfigurationLoader.java:338)
    ... 33 more
 Caused by: org.xml.sax.SAXException: Property ${main.dir} has not been set
    at com.puppycrawl.tools.checkstyle.ConfigurationLoader$InternalLoader.startElement(ConfigurationLoader.java:158)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.startElement(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.AbstractXMLDocumentParser.emptyElement(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.dtd.XMLDTDValidator.emptyElement(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.scanStartElement(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl$FragmentContentDispatcher.dispatch(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XMLParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.jaxp.SAXParserImpl$JAXPSAXParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at com.puppycrawl.tools.checkstyle.api.AbstractLoader.parseInputSource(AbstractLoader.java:98)
    at com.puppycrawl.tools.checkstyle.ConfigurationLoader.parseInputSource(ConfigurationLoader.java:273)
    at com.puppycrawl.tools.checkstyle.ConfigurationLoader.loadConfiguration(ConfigurationLoader.java:397)
    ... 34 more
```